# Reverse search from current index in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Problem statement:**
I have a **dataframe** like so:

```
   Description      Type      x      y  z
0       Branch  Actuated      0      0  0
1      Forward  Actuated   7.07   7.07  0
2    Backwards  Actuated   7.07  -2.93  0
3      Forward  Actuated  17.07  -2.93  0
4    Backwards  Actuated     10    -10  0
5      Forward  Actuated  17.07 -17.07  0
6          EOL  Actuated   7.07 -17.07  0
7      Forward  Actuated  -7.07  -7.07  0
8    Backwards  Actuated  -7.07   2.93  0
9      Forward  Actuated -17.07   2.93  0
10   Backwards  Actuated    -10     10  0
11     Forward  Actuated -17.07  17.07  0
12         EOL  Actuated  -7.07  17.07  0
13     Forward  Actuated     -0     10  0
14     Forward  Actuated     -0     20  0
15     Forward  Actuated     10      0  0
```

When an `EOL` row is encountered, the algorithm needs to reverse find the first `Branch` row and insert it after the `EOL` ro like so:

```
   Description      Type      x      y  z
0       Branch  Actuated      0      0  0
1      Forward  Actuated   7.07   7.07  0
2    Backwards  Actuated   7.07  -2.93  0
3      Forward  Actuated  17.07  -2.93  0
4    Backwards  Actuated     10    -10  0
5      Forward  Actuated  17.07 -17.07  0
6          EOL  Actuated   7.07 -17.07  0
0       Branch  Actuated      0      0  0 <--
7      Forward  Actuated  -7.07  -7.07  0
8    Backwards  Actuated  -7.07   2.93  0
9      Forward  Actuated -17.07   2.93  0
10   Backwards  Actuated    -10     10  0
11     Forward  Actuated -17.07  17.07  0
12         EOL  Actuated  -7.07  17.07  0
0       Branch  Actuated      0      0  0 <--
13     Forward  Actuated     -0     10  0
14     Forward  Actuated     -0     20  0
15     Forward  Actuated     10      0  0
```

Note: reverse search should be based on the original dataframe not the augmented one.

**Question:**
How to effifciently (resource lax and quick) accomplish this?

Comment: Is possible duplicated `Branch` values?

Comment: Since you already accomplished this, what's your current method?

Comment: Copy and paste in the question :|

Comment: @jezrael This is correct for this particular use case as there are two End of Line (`EOL`) rows and only one `Branch` row

Comment: @ZackJoubert - Yes, so in real data is only one `Branch` ?

Comment: @jezrael Not always - real data may have multiple `Branch` rows

Comment: @ZackJoubert - Is possible add it to data and change expected output? e.g. add Branch between `EOL` and after last `EOL` ?

Comment: @jezrael Apologies, I don't understand your question

Comment: @ZackJoubert - I think it should be necessary for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192564/discussion-between-zack-joubert-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) for get last matched rows, join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` for prevent duplicated index values:

```
df1 = df[df['Description'] == 'Branch']
print (df1)
  Description      Type    x    y  z
0      Branch  Actuated  0.0  0.0  0

df2 = df[df['Description'] == 'EOL']
print (df2)
   Description      Type     x      y  z
6          EOL  Actuated  7.07 -17.07  0
12         EOL  Actuated -7.07  17.07  0

df3=pd.merge_asof(df2,df1,left_index=True,right_index=True,suffixes=('_',''))[df1.columns]
print (df3)
   Description      Type    x    y  z
6       Branch  Actuated  0.0  0.0  0
12      Branch  Actuated  0.0  0.0  0

df = pd.concat([df, df3]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print (df)
   Description      Type      x      y  z
0       Branch  Actuated   0.00   0.00  0
1      Forward  Actuated   7.07   7.07  0
2    Backwards  Actuated   7.07  -2.93  0
3      Forward  Actuated  17.07  -2.93  0
4    Backwards  Actuated  10.00 -10.00  0
5      Forward  Actuated  17.07 -17.07  0
6          EOL  Actuated   7.07 -17.07  0
7       Branch  Actuated   0.00   0.00  0
8      Forward  Actuated  -7.07  -7.07  0
9    Backwards  Actuated  -7.07   2.93  0
10     Forward  Actuated -17.07   2.93  0
11   Backwards  Actuated -10.00  10.00  0
12     Forward  Actuated -17.07  17.07  0
13         EOL  Actuated  -7.07  17.07  0
14      Branch  Actuated   0.00   0.00  0
15     Forward  Actuated  -0.00  10.00  0
16     Forward  Actuated  -0.00  20.00  0
17     Forward  Actuated  10.00   0.00  0
```